# PHP: Find all products contained in an order

Tags: php, mysql

i want to notify users if all products they selected are available. I created a mysql table containing the following information:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+
| id     | order_id    | pro  | avai| 
+--------+-------------+------+-----+
| 1      | 28          | NO1  |  y  |
| 2      | 28          | NO2  |  y  |
| 3      | 28          | NO4  |  n  |
| 4      | 29          | NO8  |  y  |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+
```

I want to issue an email if all products (pro) from an order (order_id) are available (avai). The code i have so far:

```
$getData2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notify WHERE avai = 'y'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($getData2))
{
    //only gets the two with y, does not know that there is a third item that belongs to the order

}
```

That process should be automated, thats why i am not able to use a select based on the order_id.

Comment: you getting just  2 values which have avai `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, using an anti-join pattern should return the `order_id` where there are rows that are `avail='y'` and there no rows for that same order_id which are `avail='n'`:

```
SELECT a.order_id
 FROM notify a
 LEFT
 JOIN ( SELECT n.order_id
          FROM notify n 
         WHERE n.avail = 'n'
         GROUP BY n.order_id
      ) o
   ON o.order_id = a.order_id
WHERE a.avail = 'y'
  AND o.order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.order_id
```

There are other ways to get an equivalent result, such as using a NOT EXISTS predicate.

```
SELECT a.order_id
 FROM notify a
WHERE a.avail = 'y'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM notify n
                   WHERE n.order_id = a.order_id
                     AND n.avail = 'n'
                  )
GROUP BY a.order_id
```

---

If there values other than 'y' and 'n', you may need to adjust the predicates to account for those conditions as well.

The logical inverse to `avail = 'y'` would be

```
       NOT (avail <=> 'y')
```

To get only orders where ALL rows for a given order are `avail='y'`, then we'd really need to check for any rows that are "`not (avail='y')`", rather than just "`avail='n'`". And can use the null-safe comparison operator ( `<=>` ) to conveniently handle comparisons to NULL values without having to code the `OR avail IS NULL` conditions.

```
SELECT a.order_id
 FROM notify a
 LEFT
 JOIN ( SELECT n.order_id
          FROM notify n 
         WHERE NOT (n.avail <=> 'y')
         GROUP BY n.order_id
      ) o
   ON o.order_id = a.order_id
WHERE a.avail = 'y'
  AND o.order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.order_id
```

Comment: can you explain me what he want please.?

Comment: @echo_Me: he wants only orders where ALL of the rows in the table associated to the order have avail='y'. If there are rows for that order are avail='n', he doesn't want to return that order.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the n/y to Enum (statuses) 
YES|NO|NOTIFY|ORDERED|SHIPPED|RECEIVED|RETURNED

```
SELECT t1.order_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.order_id = t1.order_id) AS numOfProducts, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS t3 WHERE t3.order_id = t1.order_id AND avai = 'y') AS     
numOfAvaiProducts, 
FROM table as t1
HAVING numOfAvaiProducts = numOfProducts
GROUP BY t1.order_id
```

The Query not tested but the it should work, you get here all the orders that 
numOfAvaiProducts = numOfProducts and after notifying user you can update the 
status to notify and you dont get this result next time

Another advantage to do it like that is to save PHP code and runtime

Answer (score 0):

As your table is called notify, I assume it is just for this eMail notification?
Then you could use:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(avai SEPARATOR ',') FROM notify GROUP BY order_id
```

Then you loop through all the returned rows and explode() on ',' so you'll get an array for each row meaning for each order_id. So now, you just check the array for 'n'. If there is no 'n' in the array, you'll send the eMail and delete all rows containing that order_id. This way you don't send multiple eMails for the same order_id.

I hope that helps.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can read up on GROUP_CONCAT if you want